# Need to create replays of actor movements and actions for game

Tags: java

Here are some basics about the game:

```
- RTS (Real-time strategy)
- Every object on the game screen is an "actor".
- Every actor has an (x,y) position, HP, and type.
- Works in rounds. Every round, every actor takes one action (move, shoot, build, etc.)
```

What is the most efficient way to store up to 5000 rounds with the position and relevant information of every actor stored with each round. I would like to be able to scrub back and forth across rounds and be able to call up the relevant information on an actor for that round (i.e. an actors health on a specific round).

I know how I would do this by just writing information to a `.txt` file and then reading from it (this is how I made preset maps), but for a 5000 round match, the `.txt` file would be immense. Is there any easier way that people tackle this problem in game development? I've seen it done in RTS games quite often.

Edit - All commands are given at the beginning of the game before the game even starts. For example, the player can command something akin to "if you are a fighter - every round - find the nearest enemy and move towards it if you can't shoot it, or shoot it if you are in range. Otherwise, move south." So, there are no commands inputted after the first round begins. Rather, each actor implements the same logic every round.

Comment: Just this hint: you don't need to remember every bit of data - its enough to remember the data that actually changed from one round to another. Also, a lot of data can be replaced by just re-applying the game logic - except the parts where random elements come into play.

Comment: One more thing: maybe the [command pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/command.html#undo-and-redo) can be of help? I'm not sure, but it might make sense to just have a stack of commands, then somehow save and/or serialize those? I'm just tossing some ideas.

Comment: @domdom Only works when the logic stays the same, but problem is solvable (and interesting).

Comment: @domdom that may be useful although I'm struggling to figure out how I would implement that off the top of my head given this caveat about the game - All commands are given at the beginning of the game before the game even starts. For example, the player can command something akin to "if you are a fighter, every round, find the nearest enemy, move towards it, and shoot it. Otherwise, move south." So there are no commands inputted every round per se, rather each unit implements the same logic every round.

Comment: Dylan, that sounds as if the whole game is very deterministic, i.e. the whole course of events simply depends on the commands given at the very beginning. Shouldn't it then be enough to somehow remember those commands (I'd actually call them *rules*), then let the game logic do its thing in order to re-play? Again, random elements, if any, would need to be remembered additionally.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where are you with this problem?

Comment: I ended up using GSON to just write the attributes of every actor every round to a JSON file. Then I wrote a script to recall the attributes of every actor by round and display them on the gamescreen.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Database` is not an option you can create a `toXML()` or `toJSON()` method which creates an `XML` or `JSON` of the data for each round. After that you have to decide You can store as roundX. JSON or in bundles like `roundXtoY.JSON`. That depends on the data but it is text data, it should be pretty easy to store 100-500 (maybe a lot more) rounds at once.

Answer (score 0):

Use mappers for your attribute names, for instanced write h=100 instead of playerHealth=100
Only save changes, a static unmovable object, like a stone, does not need 5000 entries. 
Use LF instead of CRLF.

Veeery simplified Sample (where r is round, p is player, a is action, Bh is Build house):
r=0[p=0,x=100,y=100,h=100,a=Bh(101,102),p=1,x=105,y=105,h=99,a=Bh(106,106)]
~77 characters for two players each round = 385'000 bytes.

Or:
0p0x100y100h100aBh101,102,p1x105y105h99aBh106,106
Stores the same information, needs fancy code, but only 51 bytes = 255'000 bytes for 5000 rounds, that's 0.2 Megabytes. Let's say you save 10 times more data times 100 players, it's still only 200 Megabytes. If you zip it after the round, it will be reduced to about 10 MB's, I guess.

Also try to save the data with a charset that only uses only 1 byte per character, if you want to have a textfile instead of binary data.

Comment: Wouldn't it then be better to go fully binary right away? This way, some information could even be packed into a few bits, depending on how much is needed. For example, if a certain action can either be done or not done, a single bit could be enough.